# JQuery ajax error for large response

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am using spring-mvc and jquery ajax. my ajax function is

```
jQuery("#UserSearch").click(function () {
                jQuery("body").addClass("loading");
                var formValues = jQuery('#user-search').find(':input[value][value!=""]').serialize();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/SampleWebSErvice/sample/user-byName",
                    data: formValues,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 600000,
                    success: function (data) {
                        jQuery('#json').val(JSON.stringify(data)).trigger('change');
                        jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert('Error while request..' + e);
                        jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                    }
                });
            });
```

what my issue is i returned the json string from my server. It goes to the error function when response is large
 i checked through firebug it returns the correct response. and one more point is
if the response content is less means it has no problem. when it exceeds only it has problem.
In firebug response tab it says open in new Window to see the response when response is more

I don't have any server side issue because correct json is printed in both server console and browser console
am having only the large data issue.

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: it went to the error function a Error while request.Object Object Status Text :"parsererror"  when i debug i got

Comment: Try the error handler as `        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            alert('Error status: ' + textStatus);
            alert('Error message: ' + errorThrown);
            jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
        }`

Comment: Error Status - pasre error
Error message: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character  I used json2.js to display the json viewer

Comment: that is the problem, meaning the returned value is not a valid json, can you share the returned value

Comment: i got it because of the json only it says error. thank you for the detailed error function

Comment: did you figure out the problem

Comment: yes because of invalid json format.I get confused because it says error in ajax

Comment: then probably you should post it as an answer because other checking this thread will know it is already resolved

Answer (score 0):

There was an problem with json format which is returned from the server. I figured out by using the following error function

```
jQuery("#UserSearch").click(function () {
                jQuery("body").addClass("loading");
                var formValues = jQuery('#user-search').find(':input[value][value!=""]').serialize();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/SampleWebSErvice/sample/user-byName",
                    data: formValues,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 600000,
                    success: function (data) {
                        jQuery('#json').val(JSON.stringify(data)).trigger('change');
                        jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                    },
                     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error status: ' + textStatus);
                alert('Error message: ' + errorThrown);
                jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
            }
                });
            });
```